# How to embed VLC in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed, vlc

I am trying to embed a video into my HTML/ASP webpage using VLC. The box appears showing the VLC player in FireFox, but it won't play anything. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.. I've tried many different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<embed 
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
    pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
    width="640"
    height="480"
    target="file:///x:/vid.avi"
    id="vlc">
</embed>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or is it one more thing you tried?

Comment: This is the solution.

Comment: Kryptos How to render the above code on android browser. When I used it, I got an error: "chrome for android doesn't support this plugin"

Comment: VLC is disabled in Chrome v.45, so OP will need different plugin now. I use VXG Chrome plugin, for example.
It is not a direct anwer, but it is useful for those, who have found this thread, cause 'VLC doesn't work in Chrome'

Comment: Glad you found an answer! It would be preferable if you could add some explanation of this or even add what code you originally had to the question itself so people can see the change you made and easier solve the problem based on your solution.